# First difference with Pandas GroupBy does not work: 'SeriesGroupBy' object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take first difference of a multi-indexed dataframe object by its level. Multi index is (firm, year) pairs. But when I am trying to take difference by year using `.groupby(level=0).diff()`, my code throws an error: `TypeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object is not callable`.

I made this code run many times but this time it doesn't work and I couldn't figure out why.

I tried also to calculate sum, count etc. These are working well. But when I try .diff() it throws an error

I have a term-doc matrix for each firm-year and columns are the words used in the firms' text file. such as:

```
iterables = [T, Firms]
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['Time', 'Firm'])


firm_doc_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Telephone', 'Cellular', 'Digital', 'Analog', 'Internet', 'iphone', 'Android', 'Grocery'], index=index)
firm_doc_df
```

Assume now:

```
firm_doc_df.loc[(0,1)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(1,1)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(2,1)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
firm_doc_df.loc[(0,2)]=[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(1,2)]=[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(2,2)]=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(0,3)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(1,3)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
firm_doc_df.loc[(2,3)]=[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Now, when I try actual file to see the difference for a firm year-by-year:

```
firm_doc_df.groupby(level=1).diff()
```

It throws an error in the actual file (not in this example):

```
TypeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object is not callable.
```

When I try different but very similar dataframe having different shape, there seems no problem: the code works perfectly. I couldn't understand why I see such an error for the specific file I used. Any idea?

Think about a matrix having two thousand rows and sixty thousand columns. When I try to take difference in time, the code throws an error in the actual file.

Comment: The code in the question works for me

Comment: I'm able to get the error in the question with the line `firm_doc_df.loc[:, 'Cellular'].groupby(level=1)()`. So may be there are some typos somewhere in the code?

Comment: I couldn't include the real example here, it is huge. There is no error in the code for this basic example however, when I work with the actual file, it throws an error.

Comment: What is `actual file`? Script file? Data file? Provide full error traceback at least.

Comment: Interestingly, I found out that the error arises just because of one column among more than ten thousand columns in the dataframe. I dropped that specific column and now the code can take the difference in time. Still, I don't know why! Column consists of again zeros and ones.